# How to partially download CSV in python

Tags: python, csv, python-requests

I'm trying to use the `requests` library in python to download a remote CSV file. However, I only need the CSV headers, IE. the column names for each column in the CSV, and not the entire CSV file.

Is there anyway to partially download only the headers? How does the `requests` library download CSV files? Does it download it row by row?

Comment: See [Streaming Requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-requests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Justin's comment, for anyone who might be looking for a solution to this, check out https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-requests

Basically, the following code snippet will work:

```
import requests

csv_loader = requests.get(CSV_LINK_HERE, stream=True)

features = []

for line in csv_loader.iter_lines():
    if line:
        decoded_line = line.decode('utf-8')
        features = decoded_line.split(',')
        break

print(features)
```